# Не отображается иконка на сайте в поисковиках

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы

Указываю иконку в html:
`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}" type="image/x-icon">`

На самом сайте на вкладке иконка отображается, все нормально. Но, в поисковике google или yandex они не отображаются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как давно существует сайт?

Comment: Около двух недель, чуть меньше

Comment: иконка в корне сайта?

Comment: иконка по адресу https://mysite.ru/static/favicon.ico

Answer (score 0):

> На самом сайте на вкладке иконка отображается, все нормально. Но, в
> поисковике google или yandex они не отображаются.

Во первых нужно проверить соответствие требованиям ПС к фавиконке.
Во вторых индексация фавиконы - процесс длительный. Может занимать больше месяца.

Comment: А индексация описания сайта тоже длительная? Просто в google описание изменилось, а в yandex нет.

Comment: @Timofey яндексу вообще плевать на твой дескрипшен. Учи [матчать](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/indexing-options/description.html).